# PSP official firmware Game load error

Tags: psp, pspgo

I have a **PSP GO**, which runs on offical firmware *6.20*. Lately, I have been facing issues regarding game installation. Other file types work for my PSP (e.g., **Videos**, **Photos** and **Music**), but games don't work however.

I tried placing both the **iso** and the **cso**, but the game shows it is corrupted everytime

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are using **official firmware**

Official firmware **blocks** the use of installing games by placing the *ISO* or *CSO* into your PSP's directory. The only way to fix that is through the use of **custom firmware**

---

## So which do I install then?

As ythe version of your PSP is 6.20, I would recommend you install the **6.20 ME-1.9**. That is the most up-to-date version of the CFW produced by ME. Please note, make sure to read the instructions *very carefully*, and see if your model is *supported*. If not, this could potentially lead to your PSP bricking, rendering it useless.

*[Link](http://wololo.net/2014/05/10/psp-custom-firmwares-6-20-me-1-9-and-6-20-lme-1-9-with-perma-patch-are-now-available/)* to their website

---

## But wait...

If you can, however, I would strongly recomend that you instal the official **6.60** firmware, *then* installing the **6.60 ME** custom firmware. This way, you can get the most up-do-date version of ME that supports the features introduced to **6.60**

*[Link](http://wololo.net/downloads/index.php/download/948)* to their website